# Python function to parse file works for single file but not for batch

Tags: python, function

I have a function that removes part of each line of a tab delimited file, and then writes the information to a new file in a different location (with a different file extension). When I use the function on a single file, it works fine, but when I try to use it on every file in a directory (using os.listdir) I keep getting a list index out of range error. Below is my function:

```
def ext_edit(filename):
prefix = filename[0:-3]
mapfile = "location/of/new/file/" + prefix + "map"
with open(filename) as f:
    with open (mapfile, "w") as out:
        for line in f:
            x = line.split("\t")
            del x[2:4]
            out.write(x[0])
            out.write(" ")
            out.write(x[1])
            out.write("\n")
```

This works fine with a single file, but I get index out of range, with the error at `out.write(x[1])`. To test whether it would work just for `x[0]`, I removed the latter part, but then I get a "No such file or directory: "filename.txt" error.

Below is my call to apply the function on multiple files:

```
for file in os.listdir("location/of/original/file"):
    ext_edit(file)
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: Print the filename that raises an error, it may have only one tab inside...

Comment: I don't think the tag `batch-file` is suitable here?

Comment: Apologies. Have removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error result it's giving you ("No such file or directory: "filename.txt"), it might be that it's trying to open the file relative to your current working directory. You could either:

1) Use `os.chdir("location/of/original/file")` before your `for` loop:

```
os.chdir("location/of/original/file")
for file in os.listdir("location/of/original/file"):
    ext_edit(file)
```

2) Or prefix the file argument with the directory path:

```
for file in os.listdir("location/of/original/file"):
    ext_edit("location/of/original/file" + file)
```

Comment: This resolved the issue. Thanks. As to the index out of range issue, turns out that was due to a .ds_store file in the original file location. Using if file.endswith(".txt") resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

I would, if possible, use the functions provided in os.path.
Call function needs the root, too:

```
for file in os.listdir("D:/_tmp/maps"):
    ext_edit(os.path.join("D:/_tmp/maps", file))
```

The same for the function call:

```
def ext_edit(filename):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    prefix = os.path.basename(root)
    mapfile = os.path.join("D:/_tmp/maps_new", prefix + "map" + ext)
    with open(filename) as f:
       with open (mapfile, "w") as out:
          for line in f:
            x = line.split("\t")
            del x[2:4]
            out.write(x[0])
            out.write(" ")
            out.write(x[1])
            out.write("\n")
```